# Terminal.integrated.shell.{platform}" does not exist

Tags: python, windows, visual-studio-code, terminal

I'm new to coding and i've just installed Pyhton extensions in Visual Studio Code. But somehow when i tried to open Terminal, it shows error message as follows :

The terminal process failed to launch: Starting directory (cwd) "C:\Users\WIN - 10\Documents\Python\00 - Template\terminal.integrated.shell.{platform}" does not exist.

I've tried looked up into Troubleshoot Terminal launch failures documents by VSC and follows all the troubleshooting steps but still no result. Is there any solutions for my problem or i did something wrong on troubleshooting?

I really need some help because this is my first time learning to code and then this happens.
Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Have you  checked your settings/[settings.json file](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/settings#_settingsjson)? It sounds like it may have a terminal defaulted that it can't find.

Comment: My bad. I'm sorry @wjandrea i didn't mean to reply it to you.

Comment: @TimothyG. I've already checked my settings.json and found nothing. Maybe i changed the terminal defaulted accidentally without me knowing? Sorry for the late and wrong reply before

Comment: @Mikosfy No worries, I was just confused :)